# How to cast void** pointer in the correct way?

Tags: c, casting, operator-precedence

Given that

```
void func(void **structs)
{
    
    UI_Remote_s* a1 = (UI_Remote_s*)structs->Method;         //expression 
    UI_Remote_s* a2 = ((UI_Remote_s*)structs)->Method;       //correct
}
```

The first attempt is wrong. Why?

Comment: If you include the **actual error text** in a question instead of just `//compiler error`, you may actually find you question is already answered.

Comment: What you are confusing is, that the parentheses themselves are not the cast. Their inside is evaluated before `->`, true, but that only gives you the target type of the cast. Evaluating the inside of `()` does not perform the cast.

Comment: Hi. I edited the question in order to make it more clear and readable. If you think so please upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use this type of casting as it makes code much harder to read. Instead use a temporary variable to store the pointer. It will make the code easier to read and understand. The compiler is very likely to optimize it oout in the generated code.

```
UI_Remote_s **ptr = (UI_Remote_s **)structs;
a2 = (*ptr) -> Method;
a2 = (*(ptr + 5)) -> Method;
a2 = ptr[2] -> Method;
.....
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me some direction for improving context? I've changed the title as well as context for clarity but downvote is still here.